# eval-buffer doesn't do anything when setting up CLISP/SLIME

Tags: emacs, lisp, installation, slime, clisp

I am using the following tutorial:

http://www.pchristensen.com/blog/articles/installing-clisp-emacs-and-slime-on-windows-xp/

I have set-up all the directories and downloaded all the necessary files.  However, on step 4. I am using the emacs command "eval-buffer".  I type in my settings, ran "eval-buffer", received feedback (in the bottom bar), and assumed everything worked correctly.  Then when I ran M-x "slime" I received the error:

```
Spawning child process: invalid argument
```

I assumed I had typed something incorrectly in my .emacs file so I re-edited it.  However, now when I attempt to run M-x "eval-buffer" I receive no feedback and I don't believe my new code executes.

My file, by the way, is:

```
    (setq inferior-lisp-program "C:/Documents and Settings/U9UW/Desktop/root/bin/clisp/full/lisp.exe -B C:/Documents and Settings/U9UW/Desktop/root/bin/clisp/full -M 
C:/Documents and Settings/U9UW/Desktop/root/bin/clisp/full/lispinit.mem -ansi -q")
(add-to-list 'load-path "C:/Documents and Settings/U9UW/Desktop/root/bin/emacs/site-lisp/slime/")
(require 'slime)
(slime-setup)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eval-buffer actually was evaluating.  To fix the problem "Spawning child process: invalid argument", one has to replace the first line with:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program “clisp”)
```